# Convert DATASET Base64 to image in PHP

Tags: php, image, api, base64

I'm using an API to get manufacturer logos and it's returning the logo as a binary DATASET. I need to convert this into an image using PHP, but I am having a hard time with it. I can input the DATASET into some easily found tools online and it will spit out the image, I just can't get PHP to do it for me. The API says:

Returns DATASET containing the binary representation of the Logo

### The binary data from the API is as follows

```
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
```

### What I've tried

I've tried using the `imagepng` and `imagejpg` functions after decoding it using `base64_decode`, but I'm just getting a tiny little white box.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sucker looks like it's a gif.

You can deliver it to your browser like this, without converting it to anything.

```
 <img src="data:image/gif;base64,/9j/4ye-yadda-yadda-yadda-KKKACiiigD/2Q==">
```

You can save it to a `colt.gif` or other file  by base 64 decoding it and then writing that decoded data stream directly to the file. Don't use the php `image*` functions unless you want to convert it from gif to something else.

Comment: This is absolutely correct! Worked like a charm. I'll check it as correct as soon as it will let me. Thanks!

Comment: What would be the best way to convert it and save it as an image?

Comment: You're awesome! Thanks!